# Sybase Unwired Platform Hybrid Web Container IPHONE BLACKBERRY

Tags: iphone, sup

I am developing a application in Sybase Unwired Platform ,Hybrid Web Container. When I deploy it on Android it is working fine but when I deploy it on Iphone or blackberry I can see the menu items like back,next displayed on menubar and some on toolbar as it is in Iphone native application and the buttons on the screens are not working. I think its because of JQuery but is there any workaround to remove this menubar and toolbar and make it run properly.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it yet, but if you are in the last SUP version, it's supposed that you can have buttons on the screen to call SUP requests and operations without the need to add them as menuItems.

The problem with menu items is that they work different in each platform, and it's not recommended to use them anymore (even google said that), and it makes the HTML5 app less multi platform.

In my SUP apps, I hid the menuItem dynamically after the workflow initialization, and created a custom html button (using Custom.js) that calls the menuItem javascript function.